# Blocked a frame with origin "http://cdn.site.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://site.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dns

На сайте вставляю iframe. Как только он загружается, то получаю в логе:

> Blocked a frame with origin "http://remotesite.com" from accessing a
>   frame with origin "http://site.com". Protocols, domains, and ports
>   must match.

Само содержимое фрейма отображается нормально. Никаких проблем нет. Наверно, из проблем только эта красная строка в логе, которая напрягает.

В начале сообщения об ошибке говорится о блокировке фрейма (но он же не блокируется...). Дальше идет пояснения, мол, протокол, домен и порт должны совпадать (в смысле)?

В child-src и frame-src адрес прописан.

Сам проект (site.com) построен на RoR. Напускается на 3077 порту. remotesite.com - это другой сервер, не имеющий отношение к моему сайту. Я от туда черпаю только фреймы.

С YouTube, например, все нормально.

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Не нарушать Same Origin Policy или попросить сторонний ресурс сделать CORS. Или забыть о затее.

Comment: @Кнопкатык почему нет проблем с YouTube тогда? Там ведь тоже далеко все разное...

Comment: Видимо, там есть CORS.

Comment: @Кнопкатык спасибо. То что вы предоставили похоже на правду.